# Problem with updatig the state with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, state, use-effect

I want to update my state(list of objects) and I have problem with useEffect or deleteFunction.
Here's my code:

```
const [itemName, setItemName] = useState({});
const [isDeleted, setIsDeleted] = useState(false);

const createArray = () => {
   const { items } = item;
   const newNames = items.map(item => item);
   setItemName({ ...newNames });
 };


useEffect(() => {
      getItems();
      createArray();
    }, [isDeleted]);

const onDeleteClick = id => {
  deleteItem(id);
  setIsDeleted(!isDeleted);
};

console.log(itemName);

    return(
// Contaners and other things//
    item.items.map({id, name, content}, index) =>{
    // Some other code also Form and FormGroup etc. //
    <Button
       style={{
         position: "absolute",
         left: "100%",
         marginLeft: "-2.2rem",
         marginTop: "-0.8rem"
        }}
       color="danger"
       size="md"
       onClick={onDeleteClick.bind(this, _id)}
       >&times;
     </Button>
// rest of code
```

Here's deleteItem action:

```
export const deleteItem = id => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .delete(`/api/items/${id}`, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: DELETE_ITEM,
        payload: id
      })
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.error, err.response.status))
    );
};
```

and DELETE_ITEM case reducer:

```
case DELETE_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: state.items.filter(item => item._id !== action.payload)
      };
```

The problem is that after first click "itemName" didn't change, but after second it is working. So for example on start I have 10 objects, after clicking delete I should have 9 of these, but itemName have 10 of these, later number of objets is one more that this what itemName Object have.

On start: [on start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybrds.png)

On first click: [on first click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7kkb.png)

On second click: [on second click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvK6o.png)

In the end I have 0 objects, but 1 object in itemName.
Elements on list visually vanish at it should be, but if I delete some elements and try to change name or content of others elements there occurs problem with adjusting data to correct element.

And here getItems action:

```
export const getItems = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setItemsLoading());
  axios
    .get('/api/items')
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ITEMS,
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.error, err.response.status))
    );
};
```

and reducer case:

```
 case GET_ITEMS:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
```

Comment: What does getItems do?

Comment: getItems is uploading data from mongodb to item. And next I send item to ItemName.

Comment: I think I know where the problem is (you are probably not cosidering that state update is async), but can you show the whole component to be sure?

Comment: Ok, in answer there's my whole componnent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Try fetch item on did mount with:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    getItems()
},[])
```

And recreate array when items changes (in redux store):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const createArray = () => {
        const { items } = item;
        const newNames = items.map(item => item);
        setItemName({ ...newNames });
    };
    createArray();
  }, [item.items]);
```

Edit:
Using `useMemo` is probably better that the second `useEffect` and `useState` for this case

```
const itemName = useMemo( () => {
        const { items } = item;
        return items.map(item => item);
}, [item.items])
```

Comment: Great, it works. Thank you. I was also wondering what I have to do with addItem action, but I checked that it works with it without any change. I wanted to give you a vote, but I have to fill my profile, because I don't have enough reputation, but will do it in future.

Comment: Probably, because I usually use this for onChange and onSubmit functions. If it's better way to do it, I will try to learn that methods and improve my code. Again, thanks for help.

Comment: Don't worry for the vote. Try my edit, using setState (setItemName) causes rerender, avoid it if is possible

Comment: Ok, I'll try it, but I have to modify my onChangeName and onChangeContent functions. Probably I'll do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Here's whole componnent:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  Container, ListGroup, ListGroupItem, Button, Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input
} from 'reactstrap';
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getItems, deleteItem, updateItem } from '../actions/itemActions';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const MyList = ({ getItems, deleteItem, isAuthenticated, item, updateItem }) => {

  const [itemName, setItemName] = useState({});
  const [isDeleted, setIsDeleted] = useState(false);

  const createArray = () => {
    const { items } = item;
    const newNames = items.map(item => item);
    setItemName({ ...newNames });
  };



  useEffect(() => {
    getItems();
    createArray();
  }, [isDeleted]);




  const onChangeName = (item, index) => {
    return (event) => {
      const name = event.target.value;
      setItemName(prevObjs => ({ ...prevObjs, [index]: { ...item[index], name } }));
      console.log(itemName);
    }
  }
  const onChangeContent = (item, index) => {
    return (event) => {
      const content = event.target.value;
      setItemName(prevObjs => ({ ...prevObjs, index: { ...item[index], content } }));
    }
  }

  const onDeleteClick = id => {
    deleteItem(id);
    setIsDeleted(!isDeleted);
  };

  console.log(itemName);


  return (
    <Container>
      <div className="mb-3"></div>
      <ListGroup>
        <TransitionGroup >
          {item.items.map(({ _id, name, content, date }, index) => (
            < CSSTransition key={_id} timeout={500} classNames="fade" >
              <ListGroupItem className="mb-3">
                {isAuthenticated ?
                  <div>
                    <Form onSubmit={e => {
                      e.preventDefault();
                      const { name, content } = itemName[index];
                      const newItem = {
                        name,
                        content
                      }
                      // Add item via addItem action
                      updateItem(_id, newItem);
                    }}
                    >
                      <FormGroup>
                        <Button
                          style={{
                            position: "absolute",
                            left: "100%",
                            marginLeft: "-2.2rem",
                            marginTop: "-0.8rem"
                          }}
                          color="danger"
                          size="md"

                          onClick={onDeleteClick.bind(this, _id)}
                        >&times;
                  </Button>
                        <Label for="item">Header</Label>
                        <Input
                          type="text"
                          name="name"
                          id="item"
                          defaultValue={name}
                          // value={name}
                          placeholder="Add shopping item"
                          onChange={onChangeName(itemName, index)}
                        />
                        <Label for="item">Content</Label>
                        <Input
                          type="textarea"
                          name="content"
                          id="item"
                          defaultValue={content}
                          // value={content}
                          placeholder="Add shopping item"
                          onChange={onChangeContent(itemName, index)}
                        />
                        <Button
                          color="dark"
                          style={{ marginTop: '2rem' }}
                          block>
                          Change
                </Button>
                      </FormGroup>
                    </Form>
                  </div> :
                  <div>
                    <h2>{name}</h2>
                    <p>{content}</p>
                    <p>{date.replace("T", " ").slice(0, -8)}</p>
                  </div>
                }
              </ListGroupItem>
            </CSSTransition>
          ))}
        </TransitionGroup>
      </ListGroup>
    </Container>
  );
}

MyList.propTypes = {
  getItems: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  item: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  item: state.item,
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getItems, deleteItem, updateItem }
)(MyList);
```